# Touch events on parent document fire hover states in iframe in mobile safari. Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Tags: events, iframe, safari, hover, touch

Adding a touchstart event listener on a document appears to create unexpected behaviour on child iframes. It appears that hover states are triggered on items in the child iframe content when you try to scroll. I have setup an example to demonstrate this here:

To see the "bug", test this url in mobile Safari (not sure if the same issue applies to other browsers)

http://fiddle.jshell.net/tChLS/2/show/light/

When you drag over the listview, hover states are sporadically triggered on the individual list items (changing the background color)

An alternative version here has exactly the same setup but without the touchstart event listener and behaves as expected

http://fiddle.jshell.net/tChLS/3/show/light/

I need multiple touchstart listeners on the parent document and I don't want to remove the hover states in the iframed document. Does anyone have a workaround for this issue?