# Touchstart event listener is interfering with typing in a child iframe on mobile safari

Tags: html, ios, iframe, safari

I've been running into a problem with touch events and content in an iframe on mobile safari.  I have a text input box inside the iframe that a user can type in.  On the main page, outside the iframe, there's a container with a touchstart event listener.  If you start typing in the input box, then scroll around the page triggering the touchstart event, you will then no longer be able to type in the input box.  The cursor is still there and blinking, the keyboard is still displayed, keyup events continue to fire, but the characters simply don't show up in the input box.

Here are two stripped down files to display the problem:

test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test" style="height:200px;"></div>
    <iframe src="test2.html"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var test = document.getElementById('test');
        test.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){ console.log('touchstart'); });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

test2.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="input" type="text">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var input = document.getElementById('input');
            input.addEventListener('keyup', function(){ console.log('keyup'); });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you remove (or comment out) the touchstart event listener, everything works just fine.  I put some console.log statements in there just to show which events are firing and when.

I have found some discussion of similar problems (such as [Touch events on parent document fire hover states in iframe in mobile safari. Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812921/touch-events-on-parent-document-fire-hover-states-in-iframe-in-mobile-safari-is)), but haven't found anyone who's come up with an explanation or a workaround.  Has anyone else run into this problem, and have you figured out a way to workaround it?  It appears to be a mobile safari issue only, it works fine on android.